# SQL : MAX() OVER (PRITITON BY ... ORDER BY ..) : ORDER BY Clause is working looks like

Tags: sql, hive, teradata

I am trying to use `MAX(case when col4='ABC' then col1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 order by **col3**)`

```
col1~col2~col3~col4
30    A    B1   ABC
35    A    A1   ABC
36    A    NULL NULL
40    A    X1   ABC
50    B    M1   ABD
```

but I am getting the result as 40, but I want 35 as my result. It looks like

> order by col3
>   is not getting applied before MAX aggregate. Is there any other way?

I can't write the `row_number()` in where clause, as we are trying to create columns and there are many columns and complicated logic around it.

Currently I am trying it in `Teradata`, but actually it will be implemented in `HIVE`.

Comment: What do you mean "the result as 40"?  This adds a separate column with a different result on each row.

Comment: Yes, that I understand it will give a separate column. I mean the value of the separate column here

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "I want the value from MAX(col1) sorted by col3 ASC order and partition by col2" and by "order by ... is not getting applied before ...".  Given that the result of a MAX() can never be affected by whatever ORDER the input to the aggregation is in, what is it that makes you think it matters ?  You need to be clearer and more precise regarding your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  For this expression:

```
MAX(case when col4 = 'ABC' then col1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 order by col3)
```

You should be getting:

```
col1~col2~col3~col4
30    A    A1   ABC   30
40    A    X1   ABC   40
50    B    M1   ABD    0
```

If you want "30" for all, you might consider:

```
min(case when col4 = 'ABC' then col1 end) over ()
```

Comment: You didn't get the problem. MIN will not work for me. I slightly modified the problem to add one more row to clarify. I want the value from MAX(col1) sorted by col3 ASC order and partition by col2

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY` will aggregate on distinct `col2` values. Therefore, the `MAX()` value of the three col2 'A' values is 40.

If you want to return '35'.  This is suggesting that A1 is the first row returned in the partition.  First_Value() could be used to return the first row in the partition group.

```
FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN col4 = 'ABC' THEN col1 
                 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 order by col3)
```

Comment: This will not return 35 on my modified problem statement

Comment: This does return 35 -- see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc30ce947790f73b45e4983d07e95667

Comment: yes, this is working for this example but not working for my actual problem.

Comment: You need to specify additional criteria in your question.  I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: Is there anyway we can talk and share desktop for the actual problem statement?

Comment: In my case the order by working after FIRST_VALUE function, so I am not getting the correct result. Is there anyway we can enforce the ORDER BY as in FIRST_VALUE

Comment: Update your question with a minimal working example of the problem.  I can't reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: I have added one more row in the actual post and it is now showing 0 instead of 35. I believe in my case as well I am having NULL in the data

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Have moved to window function in sub query to get correct row

Sample data (as table variable)

```
declare @t table(col1 int,col2 char(1),col3 char(2),col4 char(3))
insert @t values (30,'A','B1','ABC')
,(35,'A','A1','ABC')
,(36,'A',NULL,NULL)
,(40,'A','X1','ABC')
,(50,'B','M1','ABD')
```

Query using row_number() to get row to join to

```
select t.*, mx
from @t t
join (
    select 
        col2, 
        case when col4='ABC' then col1 else 0 end as mx, 
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY col2 order by case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end, col3) rn
    from @t
    ) m on m.col2=t.col2 and rn=1
```

Result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col2    mx
30      A       B1      ABC     A       35
35      A       A1      ABC     A       35
36      A       NULL    NULL    A       35
40      A       X1      ABC     A       35
50      B       M1      ABD     B       0
```

Comment: Sometime old school things gives lots of pain ... anyway your result is not expected. The mx value I am expecting is 35 when col2=A, so your result is not correct

Comment: I was a bit too quick @KoushikChandra. Have fixed to still use a join but using row_number to get the right row.